# Env file is not read when I use docker-compose -f in a different directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a problem with my Docker `.env` file. When I'm in my Docker folder (where I have the `docker-compose.yml` and `.env` file), the environment variables are read from `.env` fine. However, when I run `docker-compose -f ./docker/docker-compose.yml up --build -d` in a higher-level directory I  get warnings like:

```
The MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

Has anyone encountered this problem? I tried setting the `env_file` property in `docker-compose.yml` and using other file encodings (I found this solution in Google) and still nothing.

This is my config:

```
version: '2'

services:
    mysql:
        container_name: mysql
        image: mysql
        volumes:
            - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
```

.env file:

```
# MySQL
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
MYSQL_DATABASE=test
MYSQL_USER=test
MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
```

Comment: According to [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/), it seems that it will only look for `.env` in the current working directory (where you run `docker-compose`). It doesn't seem like this can be changed. What happens if you try adding `env_file: .env` to your `docker-compose.yml` (as a root property at the bottom)? (Nevermind: I missed the part where you said you had).

Comment: Hello, did you find the solution to the problem?

Answer (score 2):

As Tagc says, this is the documented behavior of docker-compose with a `.env` file, it must be in the directory where you are running `docker-compose`. You cannot use `env_file` for this because that's setting a different environment. The `.env` file sets the environment used by `docker-compose` to parse the yml file (and therefore could not be set from within the file, that would be a circular dependency), while the `env_file` injects environment variables into the running containers.

If you cannot cd into the folder or move your .env file for some reason, you can manually source the file with something like:

```
env $(cat docker/.env | grep -v ^# | xargs) \
  docker-compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up --build -d
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a workaround, but it is troublesome and I am not even sure it works under all conditions. I have just tried it starting from this folder `tree`:

```
├── compose
│   └── docker-compose.test.yml
├── configs
│   └── .conf
└── envs
    └── .env
```

And this Docker-compose:

```
services:
  testing_container:
    image: mongo
    container_name: tester
    volumes:
      - ../configs/.conf:/etc/configs/.conf
    environment:
      MONGO_PORT: ${MONGO_PORT}
    ports: 
      - "${MONGO_PORT}:27017"
    env_file:
      - .env
```

Then I have run it with:

```
docker-compose -f compose/docker-compose.test.yml --project-directory ./envs up -d
```

Among the possible options there is `--project-directory` that overrides the default working directory, tricking docker into looking inside `envs` folder for the `.env` file, instead of `compose` folder. If you take a closer look at the previous `docker-compose.test.yml` you will immediately notice that you have to adapt all the other paths too, like the bind volume `../configs/.conf`, that is now relative to the `envs` folder.

Honestly, I would not recommend it unless you really have no choice.